# How to install phpbb in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpbb3

I have downloaded recent copy of phpbb3 and cakephp 2.3.5 and I have installed cakephp successfully. Now the thing is I want to install the phpbb3 and integrate it with my cakephp so that it can be accessible with url **www.mycakeapp.com/forum**.

How to do that? Where to install phpbb3 and what changes are required? Please anyone post the solution?

Comment: try putting the phpbb inside your webroot and you can acecss phpbb like this htp:\\sitename.com/phpbb

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some adjustments to your `.htaccess`. See this post for more details http://dogmatic69.com/blog/cakephp/using-other-apps-with-cakephp-htaccess-config

In short:

```
RewriteRule (some_folder/.*) $1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1:Paste the phpBB3 folder in www.mycakeapp.com/app/webroot folder.

Step2:Install it through browser.

Step3: Rename phpBB3 to forum

Step4: Inside www.mycakeapp.com/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule (forum/.*) $1 [L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now access it as www.mycakeapp.com/forum

Answer (score -1):

Extract phpbb3 in your app/webroot/forum folder. 
Then follow phpbb3 instructions at www.mycakeapp.com/forum/